# Symfony2 how can I get annotation from entity?

Tags: symfony

I have an entity

```
/**
 * @Grid\Source(columns="id, districtId")
 */

class $entity
{
}
```

How to make the ClassLoadMetadataEvent  , to read the annotation

Answer (score 0):

There should be no empty line between the PHPdoc comment and the definition of the class/method/property.

To read annotations, you'll have to use the AnnotationReader from Doctrine. You can find more information in their documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html